# Two programs blocking each other while communicating in local loop

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've programmed a simple c++ client which should communicate with another program using a listener thread (a downloaded EchoServer in Java) over the local loop on Ubuntu 14.04. However, there's a problem in the following situation:

1. Client connects to server
2. Server sends greeting message
3. Client receives message and sends a new message to server
4. Client waits for an answer; the main thread sleeps and the listener thread waits for an answer using recv()

In the next step, the server should receive the message sent by the server, but it doesn't. Instead it first receives the message once the client terminates.

I think that the problem is that the client blocks resources and thus not allowing the server to receive the message, but I'm not sure. Unfortunately I don't have the option to test this on two separate machines.

Code snippets:

```
// main method
int main(void) {
    Client client("127.0.0.1", 13050);
    std::cout << client.open() << std::endl;
    client.attachListener(foo);
    usleep(1000 * 1000 * 2);
    std::cout << client.send("hello") << std::endl;

    usleep(1000 * 1000 * 5);
}

// send method
int Client::send(const char* msg) {
    return write(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));
}

// listener function
void* Client::listen() {
    char buffer[256];
    unsigned int receive_size = 0;
    while(true) {
        receive_size =  0;
        while((receive_size = recv(sockfd, &buffer, 256, 0)) > 0) {
            buffer[receive_size] = '\0';
            msgHandler(buffer);
            bzero(&buffer, 256);
        }
        if(receive_size == 0) {
            msgHandler("Server disconnected");
        } else if(receive_size == 1) {
            msgHandler("Connection failure!");
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Output:
    1
    Welcome to the Java EchoServer.  Type 'bye' to close.
    6

Comment: Example code would help answer your question. Without it, it's hard to give a meaningful answer. Also - tagging with languages is useful.

Comment: Why is this tagged as Java?

Comment: Are you sure you have threads setup properly? Your listen function has an infinite loop. 

It is unlikely that your client is blocking resources from the server process. The client does not have exclusive access to anything the server needs (CPU, memory, network, server port).

Comment: I start the thread with `pthread_create(&listener, NULL, &Client::listenLaunch, this);` where listenLaunch is a wrapper function which calls `this->listen()`.

Comment: @mattm IIUC the server and client are on the same machine, so the client *does* have access to all resources ;-). (Whether that's the problem I don't dare say though.)

Comment: Why don't you insert generous sleep time in the while loop? (Assuming that the recv for some reason may be non blocking.) EDIT: Reading http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html a recv call on a non blocking socket would return -1 which would terminate the loop.

Comment: Reading http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recvmsg.2.html a recv call on a non blocking socket would return -1 which would terminate the inner loop but enter it right away again without a diagnostic. That would actually be true for *any* error code so that a faulty connection would never be handled (did you mean to write `} else if(receive_size == **-**1) {`??).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EchoServer` implementations typically want to see a newline on the message you send before they'll echo it back. Instead of `client.send("hello")` try `client.send("hello\n")`.

Also, though this isn't really necessary for an application you're just experimenting with, you might want to turn off the [Nagle algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle's_algorithm) on your client socket so that small messages get sent immediately. Add code like this just after the point where you call `connect` with client socket:

```
int flag = 1;
int res = setsockopt(sockfd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_NODELAY, &flag, sizeof flag);
if (res < 0) // handle setsockopt failure here...
```

This code requires these header files:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
```

Comment: It seems like the newline behind the message solved the problem. However I don't think the echo server requested this, as it did print that it had received the message. I think that the client buffered this or that the server buffered it in the OutputStream.